# Include PDF with two pages per page

Tags: pdfpages

I'm appending my papers to my thesis using the `pdfpages` package as so

```
\includepdf[pages={-}, addtotoc={1, chapter, 1, Paper 1, paper1}]{paper-1.pdf}
```

Can I modify the layout of `paper-1.pdf` such that two pages per sheet are printed?

Comment: Option `nup=2x1`. It is in the manual, which is worth reading, since it describes lots of options to customize the layout.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As mentioned by JLDiaz, you should use the `nup` option. According to the `pdfpages` documentation, the syntax of the option is: `nup=(xnup)x(ynup)`, where `(xnup)` and `(ynup)` specify the number of logical pages in horizontal and vertical direction. You may also want to use the `landscape` option in order to switch to landscape orientation and avoid twisting the neck of whoever wants to read your document on screen!

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{plain}
\includepdf[pages={1-8},nup=1x2,landscape=true]{tb88flynn.pdf}
\end{document}
```

I've printed the output to check that everything prints with the desired orientation. If you select "left bind" as binding position (or something like that) in the setup of your printer, you'll get this (after binding):

[image]
[image]

tb88flynn.pdf is available [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDQQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.tug.org%2FTUGboat%2Ftb28-1%2Ftb88flynn.pdf&ei=AcpSUeakKZGKhQfq4YGwAQ&usg=AFQjCNH7KQv8AxwQZ6vniP9VUyEgSWXHrA&sig2=amGNxlZsO5ToqGLidAdkaA&bvm=bv.44342787,d.ZG4).

Comment: I guess you want to use `angle=-90` in live production?

Comment: That's up to you, really. ±90

Comment: well, who ever reads the first page of a pdf to the right? I'm just wondering how this turns out in print because it might be relevant if the top of the site is facing inwards or outwards of the booklet.

Comment: I think `+90` makes more sense. This way, if you have your two-side document open in front of you, you can just rotate it by 90 clockwise and you'll be able to read 4 logical pages like so: 1 (Left up), 2 (right up), 3 (left down), 4 (right down).

Comment: i agree, that's the way I would want to read it. but I'm wondering how that should work, looking at the PDF you attached to your answer. If i rotate it, I had page 2 left up, then page 1 right up.

Comment: Sorry, I see what you mean now. I'll fix it right away; then we'll delete those comments and pretend I got it right the first time :)

Comment: no prob. It's good having constructive arguments.

Comment: You can use `status-lua.pdf` out of the box rather than referring to an external file.

Comment: that's actually the best way of printing it i think