# `pdfpages` `\includepdf`'s page list input options

Tags: pdfpages, loops, printing

I'd like to use `pdfpages` to make a print layout of my documents, in order to print them in A4 paper, but [with 2 pages per page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/104521/include-pdf-with-two-pages-per-page). The problem is setting the page order in a way I can cut the printed A4 sheets down to A5 size and have page 2 of the original document in the opposite side of page 1, in the same A5 sheet.

For this I would need something like:

```
\includepdf[pages={1,3,2,4,5,7,6,8},% ASSUMING A 8 PAGES FILE.
nup=1x2,landscape=true]{OriginalDoc.pdf}
```

And rotate also 180º pages 2,4,6,8, ... if the printer dialogue doesn't allow for that.

The first problem is building this ordered list for a n pages file working only inside `\includepdf` options. The second one, the rotation. After reading [`pdfpages`' manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/pdfpages/pdfpages.pdf), I see there are no many options for building the pages list.

If this approach is not possible, how would I build a loop like:

```
FOR i FROM 1 TO n-3 WITH INCREMENT(i)=4 DO
  \includepdf[pages={i,i+2},nup=1x2,landscape=true]{OriginalDoc.pdf}
  \includepdf[pages={i+1,i+3},angle=180,nup=1x2,landscape=true]{OriginalDoc.pdf}
END DO
```

? Or what other ideas may help me?

Comment: By now, I use Mathematica to generate the list I intend to generate with that loop...

Comment: Try `signature=4`?

Comment: @cfr That works for my purpose! And you also can construct this way or with option *booklet* the layout called *booklet* in typical printer dialogues, whith which you print the document and just fold the stack of papers (first printed page would contain first document page and last one, etc.).

Comment: Yes. The booklet option is very useful indeed. I suggested `signature=4` because you said you wanted to cut the stack (rather than fold it).

Comment: You may find [this answer of mine](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154810/) useful if you want to print booklets. (Note that solution 1 doesn't currently work but solution 2 does.)

Answer (score 1):

Using the `signature` option of the `pdfpages` package should do the trick:

```
\includepdf[signature=4]{OriginalDoc.pdf}
```